# Octave efficient way to repeat an array

Tags: octave, cycle

Hi I have a 2D array in Octave, called Sig in the code, and I want to replicate this repeatedly to form a certain number of cycles of this array. The way I've written is working but very slow, am I missing a trick to speed this up?

```
Cycles=262800
Sig_1=Sig
for i=1:1:Cycles-1;
Sig_1=[Sig_1;Sig];
endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `repmat`:

```
Sig_1 = repmat(Sig, [Cycles, 1])
```